# Http request with Python

Tags: python, web

I am not to familiar with Python so I wanted to ask you for help. I am trying to make a Toolkit for Instagram so I need a method to log one in but I dont know how to make this request and with which url. So can you help me and show me a Tool to find out to which url I need to make which request. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is completely unrelated to server administration and enterprise information system administration. You should ask elsewhere; possibly stackoverflow, though your question isn't precise enough for this site either.

Comment: @wazoox But I thought on this site you can ask for tools for server administraton and I guessed you know some tools for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations on your first post. Welcome!

I think you have the "tool" right here in your web browser. At least if you're using Chrome (or another webkit browser) or Firefox, the "Developer Tools" have a "Network" tab that shows all the traffic the browser sends back and forth. Including URLs, HTTP headers and all POST, GET parameters, etc.

Hit F12, and go to the Network tab. I use Firefox, and this is what it looks like when loading this very page:

[image: network tab in firefox]

The log in process may require multiple page loads. If so, you can enable the "Persist Logs" checkbox to see all the redirects etc. (I believe Chrome has the Persist Logs feature too, just hidden in a preference page somewhere). That will work in the general case.

Often times, though, popular web pages go to great lengths to make it difficult for such manual HTTP(s) traffic/reverse engineering/screen scraping and/or it might be in breach of their terms of service. (Which means that when/if your tool becomes popular, they'll make sure it doesn't work, and perhaps ban any users trying to use it).

You might be better off using the API. I quick google search revealed that Instagram indeed does have such a [Instagram Basic Display API - Instagram Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/). I've never tried it.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.